# Usar Link de Nextjs con React-Materialize en el brand del NavBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

integrando **React-Materialize** con **Nextjs** obtengo un error de consola al usar Link dentro del brand de NavBar la única solución que he encontrado es solo dejar `<a className="brand-logo">GG</a>` sin el componente `<Link>` pero su renderizado es muy lento al usarlo de esa manera alguna sugerencia he intentado de todo aquí dejo el código del componente:

```
import { Navbar, Icon, } from 'react-materialize';
import Link from 'next/link'

const NavigationBar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar className="teal"
      alignLinks="right"
      brand={<Link href="/"><a className="brand-logo">GG</a></Link>}
      id="mobile-nav"
      menuIcon={<Icon>menu</Icon>}
      options={{
        draggable: true,
        edge: 'left',
        inDuration: 250,
        onCloseEnd: null,
        onCloseStart: null,
        onOpenEnd: null,
        onOpenStart: null,
        outDuration: 200,
        preventScrolling: true
      }}
    >
      <Link href="Products">
        <a>Products</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="About">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="Cart-Shop">
        <a>Cart-Shop</a>
      </Link>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default NavigationBar
```

y este es el error que arroja la consola:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Link: unknown props found: className   checkPropTypes.js?a15c:20 
in Link (at NavBar.js:8)
in Navbar (at NavBar.js:6)
in NavigationBar (at Index.js:17)
in Index (at _app.jsx:7)
in MyApp
in ErrorBoundary (created by ReactDevOverlay)
in ReactDevOverlay (created by Container)
in Container (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in Root
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Una de las maneras que he tratado ha sido incluir el className dentro de `<Link>` pero este no recibe className como props el className debe ir obligatoriomante dentro de la etiqueta`<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma que logre fue usar `<Router>`, elimine `<Link>` del brand y solo deje la etiqueta con un evento onClick utilizando el metodo push `<a className="brand-logo" onClick={() => Router.push('/')}>GG</a>` y en el css global usar el cursor pointer para la etiqueta `<a>` de alguna manera `<Link>`es un poco testarudo y no funciona dentro de algunos elementos ya que es un HOC es mi deducción a este problema , con esto se eliminaron los mensajes en la consola y cuando renderizo el brand no recarga toda la pagina aqui el codigo:

```
import { Navbar, Icon, } from 'react-materialize';
import Router from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'

const NavigationBar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar className="teal"
      alignLinks="right"
      brand={<a className="brand-logo" onClick={() => Router.push('/')}>GG</a>}
      id="mobile-nav"
      menuIcon={<Icon>menu</Icon>}
      options={{
        draggable: true,
        edge: 'left',
        inDuration: 250,
        onCloseEnd: null,
        onCloseStart: null,
        onOpenEnd: null,
        onOpenStart: null,
        outDuration: 200,
        preventScrolling: true
      }}
    >
      <Link href="Products">
        <a>Products</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="About">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="Cart-Shop">
        <a>Cart-Shop</a>
      </Link>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default NavigationBar
```